# Issues with creating excel files in php

Tags: php, excel, xls

I'm using a library called "ExcelWriterXML" in PHP to create excel files.

They are created in format .xls and I myself doesn't have any problem opening them.

Unfortunately, my customers do. When they try to open the file they get an error saying that the file is corrupt.

I have tried to change the code so it creates a file with .xlsx format instead, but then the file doesn't work for me. (I'm supposed to have the latest excel reader so shouldn't be a problem with my software)
I can't seem to understand what the problem is, so now I turn to you!

Any ideas what may be causing the problem?

Thank you for all the help!

Comment: What format are the files actually saved as? (Don't make assumptions purely because the extension is .xls) A .xls extension suggests BIFF; but the library name suggests an XML format like OfficeOpen XML or SpreadsheetML?

Comment: What software are you/the client using to view the file?  Excel is the obvious choice, but what about LibreOffice?

Comment: Are you using the same version of Excel as your clients?

Comment: @MarkBaker What you are saying Mark seems to actually be the problem. The file is probably saved as XML. That would mean that i have to change the library that i'm using. Do you have any good suggestions? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Bror - As the developer of PHPExcel (https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel or http://phpexcel.codeplex.com) I do have a certain bias in any suggestion I'm likely to make

Comment: @MarkBaker If it can do what is says it does then it's perfect for me :) Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that it uses column index starting from zero. Change the line in excelWriterXML_Sheet.php line 335:

```
$column
```

to

```
 $column + 1
```

It should solve the problem.